# How to refresh a portlet on a page where there is more portlets? (liferay-7.2)

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, liferay-7.2, searchcontainer

I have a portlet "Portlet A" that displays a content and calls another portlet "Portlet B" with "runtime". So I have two portlets on the same page.

The "Portlet B" has a search-container. When I click on next or page 2 in the search-container it sends me back, I think this is so because it takes the url of the search-container portlet.

Is there any way that it just refreshes "Portlet B" (search-container portlet) and doesn't send me out?

Portlet A:

```
<liferay-util:buffer var="call">
        <liferay-portlet:runtime portletName="com_liferay_document_portlet_DocumentFormPortlet" queryString='<%= "&id=" + String.valueOf(id) %>' />
</liferay-util:buffer>
```

Portlet B:

```
<%
...
PortletURL portletURL = renderResponse.createRenderURL();
portletURLViews.setParameter("id", String.valueOf(id));
portletURLViews.setParameter("docsCur", docsCur);
...
%>

<liferay-ui:search-container
    emptyResultsMessage="Nothing"
    id="docs"
    total="<%= docs.size() %>"
    curParam="docsCur"
    iteratorURL="<%= portletURL %>"
>
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results
        results="<%= ... %>"
    />
        
    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
        ...
    >
        ...
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
    <liferay-ui:search-iterator/>
</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

Could you help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't use search containers - they refresh the page ! use data-tables or some other components which can work on AJAX